# How to import from Google Keep or save all locally?

Tags: import, google-keep

I have a lot of notes in Google Keep. Can I save this info locally on computer or import to MS Word? Not every note separately but all together?

Comment: (There's apparently no way to do it from the Android app, either.)

Comment: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/01/introducing-google-drive-android-api.html Google Drive API for Android has been published two days ago, lets hope web interface / API comes after that relatively soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it will select all of the individual notes with its own interface. On the top, the yellow horizontal bar will become dark grey. The rightmost button of the center grouping is three vertical dots. If you click that, there's an option to *Copy to Google Doc*. Click that and there's a little dialog box that will soon give you a link that says "OPEN DOC," which will take you to your new "Google Keep Document" on Google Drive. If you have a lot of notes, it will take a long time to load it all, but then you can copy and paste that as plaintext or use Google Docs' built-in export options for Microsoft Word.

(Personally, I wish there was a way to keep them separated in this document, or to export them each as individual notes, but that's not possible at the moment, as far as I can tell. This would be useful for actually exporting to other notetaking apps and keeping the data fully intact. Unfortunately, Google Takeout still doesn't support it, but I imagine that will be the way to save the notes individually eventually.)

Comment: yes, looks like it's right answer

Answer (score 5):

You can now go to https://google.com/takeout and choose Keep as an option.  This will create an archive of hyperlinked HTML notes that should contain all of your content.

Comment: yes, very interesting way to get data from Keep

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this script (I haven't tested it):

```
/* Vedant Misra (vedantmisra.com) (github.com/vedant)
*
* Script for exporting Google Keep note files.
*
* This does not handle attachments or checklists, only note files. Downloads
* each note to a .txt file named for the note's title.
*
* To use this, go to https://drive.google.com/keep/ and wait for the page to
* fully load all of your saved notes; scroll to the bottom to confirm they're
* loaded. Then paste the below in your URI bar, go to the start of the line,
* prepend what you pasted with "javascript:" without quote marks, and hit enter.
*
* REVISED for Google Keep update. 2014-09-14
*/

(function(){"use strict";var e=document.createElement("SCRIPT");e.src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";e.type="text/javascript";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);var t=function(e){if(window.jQuery){e(jQuery)}else{window.setTimeout(function(){t(e)},100)}};t(function(e){(function(e){e.save=function(t,n){if(!t){e.error("Console.save: No data");return}if(!n){n="console.txt"}if(typeof t==="object"){t=JSON.stringify(t,undefined,4)}var r=new Blob([t],{type:"text/text"}),i=document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),s=document.createElement("a");s.download=n;s.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(r);s.dataset.downloadurl=["text/text",s.download,s.href].join(":");i.initMouseEvent("click",true,false,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);s.dispatchEvent(i)}})(console);var t=e(".IZ65Hb-YPqjbf.h1U9Be-YPqjbf"),n=e(".IZ65Hb-YPqjbf.r4nke-YPqjbf");for(var r=1;r<=t.length;r++){t[r].click();var i=e('.IZ65Hb-YPqjbf.h1U9Be-YPqjbf[contenteditable="true"');console.save(i[1].innerText,n[r].innerHTML+".txt")}alert(t.length-1+" files downloaded.")})})()
```

[(source)](https://gist.github.com/vedant/9333992)